# Read data from database in format row[field] -> value

Tags: android

I got really confused with the database usage in Android.

I have this database:

Table name: **articles**
Fields: **id**, **article**, **chapterid**

i currently have the below code and use it inside a fragment:

```
List<Comment> contents = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).connectRawQueryDB("database.sqlite", "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE chapterid = 1");
```

And in my MainActivity

```
    public List<Comment> connectRawQueryDB(String DB_NAME, String RawQuery) {
        List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<Comment>();

        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(RawQuery,null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
          Comment comment = cursorToComment(cursor);
          comments.add(comment);
          cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        // make sure to close the cursor
        cursor.close();
        return comments;
}

private Comment cursorToComment(Cursor cursor) {
        Comment comment = new Comment();
        comment.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
        comment.setComment(cursor.getString(1));
        return comment;
}
```

What i need is to make a query to the database and then output values in the following format:

e.g. **row[article]** and get the **value** of article and from the same query get row[id] and get the value in id field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this method in you dbhandler....

```
 public ArrayList<Comment> getCommentdata()
{
    //get db
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    ArrayList<Comment> resultCommentList = new ArrayList<Comment>();

    String resultQuery = "select id, article, chapterid from "+YOUR_TABLE;

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(resultQuery, null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            Comment commentObject = new Comment();
            commentObject.setcommentUID(cursor.getInt(0));
            commentObject.setarticle(cursor.getString(1));
            commentObject.setChapterID(cursor.getInt(2));
            resultCommentList.add(commentObject);
        }
        while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    //close db
    if(db != null)
        db.close();

    return resultCommentList;
}
```

And when yout want to retrive data

```
 allComent = localDBHelper.getCommentdata();

     for(int i = 0; i < allComent .size(); i++)
{
       int id=allComment.get(i).getcommentUID();
       String =allComment.get(i).getarticle();
       int cid=allComment.get(i).getChapteID();

    }
```

Comment: It is not a copy paste solution, but is well written and helped me understand the database usage better. This actually solved my problem!